# How do I use subprocess.getoutput to properly execute an ssh command to retrieve the contents of a file

Tags: python, docker, flask, containers, openssh

END GOAL: Build a flask app that can ssh into a remote machine that then remotes to a remote device (via agent forwarding) and fetches the value of a config file on that device.

PROBLEM: I have a script that works when I run the flask app on my local machine. It fetches and displays the values of the config from the remote device. But when I build a docker container to host the flask app, I only ever receive a Permission denied (publickey). error from the api. I have the docker container set up in a way that I am able to execute the exact same ssh script to fetch the config from the container's terminal. But even if I curl the api it gives me the same permission denied error.

This is my little flask api and script to fetch the contents of the config.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.get('/api/v1/remote/config')
def ssh_show_config():
    user = request.args.get('user')
    host = request.args.get('host')
    node = request.args.get('node')
    return jsonify(get_config_via_ssh(user, host, node))

def get_config_via_ssh(user, host, tunnel_ip):
    try:
        cmd2 = f"ssh -A -tt {user}@{host} -tt \"ssh root@{tunnel_ip} 'cat /storage/config'\""
        process = subprocess.getoutput(cmd2, encoding='utf-8')
        # ConfigCleaner is just a tool that cleans the data in the config
        cleaner = ConfigCleaner()
        return cleaner.clean(process)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("[!] Cannot connect to the device SSH Server")
        exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.11-slim-bullseye

# update/install necessary alpine linux libraries
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN apt-get install -y openssh-client
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y sudo

RUN adduser tester
RUN adduser tester sudo

RUN pip3 install poetry

# create project directory
WORKDIR /root/config-app
COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 22

# install required python libraries via poetry
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false
RUN poetry install

USER tester

# switch to app directory and run app
WORKDIR /root/config-app/src/config_fetcher

CMD poetry run flask --app app run --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000
```

This is my docker-compose

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  config-fetcher:
    image: config-app
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ~/.ssh/config:/root/.ssh/config:rw
      - ~/.ssh/id_ed25519:/root/.ssh/id_ed25519:rw
      - ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub:/root/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub:rw
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "22:22"
```

After I run docker compose up, I execute the following command in the container's terminal in order to 1. add a blank known_hosts file and a sockets directory and 2. start the ssh agent and add my mounted key to it in the container:

`touch ~/.ssh/known_hosts && mkdir ~/.ssh/sockets && eval` ssh-agent `&& ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519`

After all of that, I am able to execute

`ssh -A -tt user@host.domain.com -tt ssh root@device.ip cat /storage/config`

inside the container's terminal and it will successfully return the content of the config file (just as I've designed the flask api to do). However, if I curl the api endpoint I created for my flask app (from within the same container), it gives me the permission error. None of this is a problem if I run the flask app on my local machine without the use of docker.

I'm really beating myself over the head on this one.

Comment: Don't use `subprocess` for SSH. Use the `paramiko` library.

Comment: I tried paramiko first and I couldn’t get it to connect at all. No matter how I configured it, it would timeout trying to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of problems here.

1. Your use of `ssh-agent` is ineffective.

   Because you're only starting ssh-agent as part of your interactive `docker exec` session, the agent isn't going to be visible to the `ssh` process spawned by your flask application.
2. I'm suspicious of your `ssh` command line, because you've got three levels of quoting going on.

   By ditching `getoutput` in favor of `check_output` and specifying the command as a list instead of a string, we can simplify things.

   We can further simplify things by using the `-J` option to ssh to specify a jump host.
3. `EXPOSE` in a Dockerfile does nothing (it's just informative).

---

We can fix your code by writing it like this:

```
import subprocess
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.get("/api/v1/remote/config")
def ssh_show_config():
    user = request.args.get("user")
    host = request.args.get("host")
    node = request.args.get("node")
    return jsonify(get_config_via_ssh(user, host, node))


def get_config_via_ssh(user, host, tunnel_ip):
    try:
        cmd = [
            "ssh",
            "-A",
            "-J", f"{user}@{host}",
            f"root@{tunnel_ip}",
            "cat /tmp/config",
        ]
        config = subprocess.check_output(cmd, encoding="utf-8", stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        return {"config": config}
    exception Exception as e:
        return {"error": f"Cannot connect to the device SSH Server: {e}"}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

I've rewritten the Dockerfile using `pipenv` instead of `poetry` (because I'm not familiar with poetry) and removed a bunch of extraneous code that wasn't relevant to this example.

I've also modified the Dockerfile to run your application under the control of `ssh-agent`, with an explicit agent socket so that we can interact with the same agent from an interactive session:

```
FROM python:3.11-slim-bullseye

# update/install necessary alpine linux libraries
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y openssh-client

RUN pip install pipenv

# create project directory
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pipenv install -r requirements.txt
COPY . ./
RUN mkdir -m 700 -p /root/.ssh && cp ssh_config /root/.ssh/config && chmod 600 /root/.ssh/config

ENV SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/agent.sock

CMD ["ssh-agent", "-a", "/tmp/agent.sock", "pipenv", "run", "flask", \
    "--app", "app", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "5000"]
```

Lastly, I've updated the `compose.yaml` to mount an ssh key as a [docker secret](https://docs.docker.com/compose/use-secrets/):

```
services:
  config-fetcher:
    image: flaskapp
    user: root
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    secrets:
      - sshkey

secrets:
  sshkey:
    file: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

This means that when the container runs, my ssh key will be available as `/run/secrets/sshkey`.

---

With all of this in place, if I `docker compose up` the container, I can then start an interactive session and load the key:

```
$ docker compose exec config-fetcher ssh-add /run/secrets/sshkey
Enter passphrase for /run/secrets/sshkey:
Identity added: /run/secrets/sshkey (/run/secrets/sshkey)
```

And then the following request works:

```
$ curl localhost:5000/api/v1/remote/config'?user=lars&host=172.20.0.1&node=127.0.0.1'
{"config":"this is a test\n"}
```

Comment: All the code referenced in this answer can be found in [this repository](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-77025746-flash-ssh).